# How to loop over elements in a json list Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

I have an issue where ajax can see the data I've given it from flask, but it doesn't seem to be parsing inside when I loop it. This is currently a 1 item loop, but it will be more when data is fed into it.

Json string is:

```
{ "routers" : {"DNSROOTSERVER": {"os": "4.4.4.4", "name": "DNSROOTSERVER"}}}
```

so it understands data.routers, and it even understands data.routers.DNSROOTSERVER.name (as you'll see in the console.log), but when I use a loop over data.routers, the looped item displays (el), but  it seems to fail when i try el.name, saying it's undefined. Javascript is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "{{ url_for('.gui_form') }}", dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        console.log(data)
        $(data.routers).each(function(i, el) {
            console.log(el)
            console.log(el.os)
            console.log(data.routers.DNSROOTSERVER.os)
            var listem = "<br>" + el.name;
            $("#routers").append("<li>" + listem + "</li>");
        });
    }
    });
});
```

I've expanded the console log so you can see the data is there and how the looped el.os comes out undefined but data.routers.DNSROOTSERVER.name comes out cleanly as ios:

```
Object {routers: Object}routers: ObjectDNSROOTSERVER: Objectip: "4.4.4.4"name: "DNSROOTSERVER"os: "ios"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
Object {DNSROOTSERVER: Object}DNSROOTSERVER: Objectip: "4.4.4.4"name: "DNSROOTSERVER"os: "ios"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
undefined
ios
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: from what i can see in your json you don't need any loops

Comment: based on your javascript the json shoud look like `{ "routers" :[ {"os": "4.4.4.4", "name": "DNSROOTSERVER"}]}`

Comment: try $(data.routers.DNSROOTSERVER).each(...)

Comment: @madalinivascu I'll try reformatting the json like you suggested

Comment: @madalinivascu you're right, my json was malformed for what i wanted to do with it, if you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @KeefBaker see answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your javascript the json shoud look like `{ "routers" :[ {"os": "4.4.4.4", "name": "DNSROOTSERVER"}]}`

Comment: Yep. As you said, my json was malformed. Thanks! Much appreciated.